# How to reduce the total after every iteration

Tags: php

I have a $paymentsTotal variable which is the sum of all payments. I then want to loop through all outstanding amounts and reduce the $paymentsTotal variable for each outstanding amount.

eg:

```
TotalPayments = 900 - 200
                700 - 300
                400 - 100
                300 - 300
Stop             0
```

And as long as the $paymentsTotal is greater than the outstanding amount, it should return true.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
  if($paymentTotal >= $paymentTotal -= $invoice->amount) {
        echo $invoice->amount . ' - PAID <br>';
   }
}
```

but it echos out each result no matter what.

Comment: dont use autodecerement operator inside if as it has undefined behaviour. better decerement before or after the if and check then

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```php
$paymentTotal = 0; // whatever this is before iteration

foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
    if ($invoice->amount > $paymentTotal) {
        $paymentTotal -= $invoice->amount; // assuming you have a field for the paid amount
        $invoice->amount = $paymentTotal; // new invoice amount
    echo "{$invoice->amount} - PAID <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but it doesn't seem to work as expected. It seems like Nikos M's advice was good. `foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
   $something = $paymentTotal - $paymentTotal -= $invoice->amount;
   if($paymentTotal >= $something) {
       echo $invoice->amount . ' - PAID <br>';
   }
}`

Comment: You're welcome. Please reply with that code and accept your answer so other users can see what you did to fix that issue.

Comment: Perhaps Nikos could create an answer so I can mark that as the answer.